# Read json with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi all I would like to read a json file with angular but I am not able too and I get the flowing error

```
 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ng/areq?
p0=jsonCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

 (anonymous) @ angular.js:12330
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9109
$apply @ angular.js:15947
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1633
 e @ angular.js:4450
d @ angular.js:1631
Ac @ angular.js:1651
Zd @ angular.js:1545
 (anonymous) @ angular.js:28359
  a @ angular.js:2996
 c @ angular.js:3271
```

***My code is index.html is***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="myApp">

 <head>
  <title>Angular Quickstart</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Polyfills -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js">
</script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('main.js').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
     myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
         $http.get('data.json').success(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response;
         });
     });
   </script>

   </head>

    <body ng-controller="myController">
     Search : <input type="text" value="" ng-model="search" />
     <table border=1>
         <tr ng-repeat="data in myData | filter : search">
         <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{data.Company}}</td>
           <td><a href="" ng-click="removeName(data)">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
       <div ng-controller="jsonCtrl">

        <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
    </body>

  </html>
```

I have looked a lot but I cannot figure it out. Does this script have to be in different file? or is it good in index.html?I am really new to angular and I have no clue how to approach this problem

Comment: This code is angularjs **not** angular 2. The syntax is very different and you can see in the version number of your src: `1.4.3`.

Comment: @Amir i have created codepen with online api and it works fine and the error you are getting becuase you didnt create any controller jsonCtrl

Answer (score 1):

You are using both angularJs and angular 2!, the error you are getting is because of this line

`<div ng-controller="jsonCtrl">`

There is no controller with name `jsonCtrl`

But as I said you are using AngularJs and Angular2!